# Trying to build a simple coffee-ordering app using C# - Not adding up Total Cost of Coffees

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I am trying to make a simple coffee app using C#. However, it is not adding up the total price of Coffees at the end. Below is my code:

```
using System;

namespace Coffee_Program
{
    class Coffee
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start:

            int TotalCoffeePrice = 0;

            System.Console.WriteLine("Our coffee shop sells 3 sizes of coffee");
            System.Console.WriteLine("1 is Small, 2 is Medium and 3 is Large");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Enter a number below corresponding to the size of the coffee:");
            int UserSelection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             
            switch (UserSelection)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("You chose the Small Coffee.");
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"It costs 1 dollar");
                    TotalCoffeePrice += 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("You chose the Medium Coffee");
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"It costs 2 dollars");
                    TotalCoffeePrice += 2;
                    break;
                
                case 3:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("You chose the Large Coffee");
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"It costs 3 dollars");
                    TotalCoffeePrice += 3;
                    break;

                default:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("You did not choose a number between 1-3. Please choose again");
                    goto Start;
            }

        YesOrNo:

        System.Console.WriteLine("Do you want to buy another coffee? - Yes or No");
        string UserChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (UserChoice.ToUpper())
        {
            case "YES":
                goto Start;
            case "NO":
                break;
            default:
                System.Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid choice. Please enter Yes or No");
                goto YesOrNo;
        }


        System.Console.WriteLine("Thank your for ordering your coffees.");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Your total cost was {TotalCoffeePrice} dollars");

        }
    }
}
```

If I try to enter a small and large coffee, the TotalCoffeePrice returns just the price of the large coffee. What do I do.

I know using goto is not good practice but I am yet to learn loops. What is going wrong here.

Comment: first things first; get rid of `goto`!

Comment: _"I know using goto is not good practice but I am yet to learn loops"_ Is this an assignment? Because you shouldn't be given an assignment that requires repetition before learning loops. If, on the other hand, you're learning on your own, then definitely start with loops and do not use `goto` (especially to jump backwards).

Comment: It is an assignment yes (not graded though). Our teacher very specifically said that he wanted us to know what goto is but will not use it further after we learn loops in 3 days.

Comment: Well, the problem is that `int TotalCoffeePrice = 0;` is called each time you go to `Start`; effectively discarding whatever value you had before.

Comment: I do think your teacher is wrong though. Using `goto` in that manner is tempting (especially for beginners) because it makes things appear "convenient". However, it makes your life miserable later when you want to debug your code. Teaching it in this way before teaching loops is not a good idea, IMO. Some students might get used to it and prefer it over loops.  But that's beside the point anyway.

Comment: AHHHH I got it now. I reset it and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't change the syllabus now, but I will keep what you said in mind. Maybe I will learn loops and rewrite this program

Comment: What do you mean "reset it"? You should just move it before `Start:`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you can't ask for homework here

Comment: @IvanIčin OP is not asking for us to write their homework. Asking about a specific issue that one might have while _attempting_ to solve the problem [is certainly allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/8967612#:~:text=It%20is%20okay%20to%20ask%20about%20homework).

Comment: @41686d6564 as quoted in the link it is a matter of personal feeling. Three people with reputation enough to vote thought that this is not an OK question and it is closed. Your opinion is different. It is OK to have a different opinion, I do understand your position.

Comment: @IvanIčin Actually, I was one of those users (well, the first) who voted to close the question; but for a different reason. I believe it should be closed because the problem is trivial and is unlikely to help future readers (or alternatively, because it's a scope issue that has been asked and answered a zillion times before). But definitely not because it's homework-related. As I stated above, homework-related questions seeking help with a _specific_ problem (as opposed to a "do this for me" type of question) are certainly allowed.

Comment: @41686d6564 I do understand your opinion, but the homework is structured so that only 'do this for me' question is possible. If it goes beyond that I wouldn't call it a 'homework' even if it is school related, it is more a 'school project' or something like that. So I do stand behind the words though it is more of a semantic than logical disagreement I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `TotalCoffeePrice` only once in your code it will be reset to zero each time you go to `Start:`

```cs
int TotalCoffeePrice =0;  \\ << intialze befor start
Start:
\\... the loop body
```

You should update `TotalCoffeePrice` with the corresponding price for each coffee

```cs
 switch (UserSelection)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("You chose the Small Coffee.");
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"It costs 3 dollars");
                    \\TotalCoffeePrice += 1;
                    TotalCoffeePrice += 3; \\<<<<  the correct price to small coffee
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("You chose the Medium Coffee");
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"It costs 5 dollars");
                    \\TotalCoffeePrice += 2;
                    TotalCoffeePrice += 5;  \\<<<< increase the total price by the coast of Medium coffe which is 5
                    break;
                
                case 3:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("You chose the Large Coffee");
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"It costs 7 dollars");
                    \\TotalCoffeePrice += 3;
                    TotalCoffeePrice += 7;  \\<<<<<<<<<<
                    break;

                default:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("You did not choose a number between 1-3. Please choose again");
                    goto Start;
            }
```